# Linq to Entities Many to Many return nested objects

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

If I have three tables in a many to many relationship, including the junction table, Students, StudentCourses, Courses:

How can I return the Student objects with their associated course objects?

To further clarify, here is the Student View model:

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public ICollection<StudentCourseViewModel> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

The following Linq to Entities query only returns student objects, hence my problem!

```
var query = from student in context.Students
            from studentcourse in student.StudentCourses
            where studentcourse.CourseID == 4
            select student;
```

Unfortunately, in the View when I debug the student object, there are no studentcourses being returned. Looking at the syntax of the query, this makes sense as it is only returning students.

I've tried projection, e.g.

```
var query = from student in context.Students
            from studentcourse in student.StudentCourses
            where studentcourse.CourseID == 4
            select new
            {
                student,
                StudentCourses = studentcourse
            }
```

But projection reshapes the output Student object and does not meet the Student shape(type) since I'm using the Student view model.

Here is a snippet of my View code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 @Html.DisplayFor(s => item.Name)
 ...
 ...

 @foreach (var subItem in item.StudentCourses)
 {
  @Html.DisplayFor(sc => subItem.Description)
  @Html.DisplayFor(c => subItem.Course.Name)
  ...
```

So, really stuck at this point. I would have thought this would be very simple, but I've spent an entire day researching, trial and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the related entities to be loaded by using `Include`:

```
var query = from student in context.Students
                                   .Include("StudentCourses")
                                   .Include("StudentCourses.Course")
            where studentcourse.CourseID == 4
            select student;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I may be forced to use Includes, so the result type remains the same type being queried, i.e. Student. I was hoping to avoid the use of Includes (due to potential performance issues), but I don't think there is another option. Projection results in anonymous types, which I now see I cannot use, as I cannot pass an anonymous type to my view model.